# need AES Decryption in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, angular, encryption, cryptojs

I have the following code for decryption in java, I want that to be implemented in angular4.

```
public synchronized InputStream getInputStream(String src) {
    KeyEntry entry = keysMap.get(src);
    try {
        String destPath = rootFolder + "/" + entry.destination;
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(destPath);
        if (entry.key.isEmpty()) return is;
        byte[] encKey = Base64.decode(entry.key, Base64.DEFAULT);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(encKey, AES_ALGORITHM);
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(encKey);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_TRANSFORMATION);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        return new CipherInputStream(is, cipher);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

currently doing it, something like below, not working

```
decryptContent(ciphertext, base64Key) {
    const key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(base64Key);

    const decryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt( ciphertext, key, {
        iv: CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8),
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding
    });

    const decryptedText = decryptedData.toString( CryptoJS.enc.Utf8 );    
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is not working? Are you sure the Java app is using ECB mode with no padding? As well you cannot have random IV when decrypting, see how the Java code computes IV (using a key as IV is not good either)

Comment: AES_TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CFB8/NoPadding";
I don't understand how to get the IV in javascript as in java, that is where I am majorly struck.

Answer (score 1):

> AES_TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CFB8/NoPadding";

Then you need to use CFB mode as well for decryption

```
 mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB
```

> I don't understand how to get the IV in javascript as in java, that is where I am majorly struck

```
IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(encKey);
```

In Java the encryption key is used as IV as well. To decrypt the data you should use the key as IV too.

Please note using key as IV is bad practice and it may create security weakness. IV allows reusing the same key for multiple encryptions without creating an opening for the "two-time  pad attack". If the key is reused for multiple encryptions, IV needs to be unique for each encryption for the same key.